# Using Apache Reverse Proxy to have 1 Public IP for various Servers

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, amazon-route53

I'm using AWS for my servers.

I have made several instances that run different http websites locally. (instance1, instance2, ....)

I have registered a domain `example.com` and made a hosted zone `example.com` on my Route 53.

I have made an instance which runs Apache httpd which I use as a reverse proxy.
With this server I have associated my public, elastic IP from AWS. This server is in the same network as the website servers.
After that I have made a record table in route 53 that makes `proxy.example.com` point to the public IP of my proxy server and another record table that makes `instance1.example.com` point to the private adress of one of the website hosting servers.

Then in the httpd config file on the proxy server i added this code:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://instance1.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://instance1.example.com/"
```

If I now type `proxy.example.com` into any browser I get redirected to the website that runs on instance1 which is pretty neat.

As a final touch I would now like to get redirected by this proxy server to my different servers with different websites depending on the subdomain I enter:

If I enter `instance1.example.com`, the traffic should go to my proxy which then sees the subdomain and redirects said traffic to my instance1.

If I enter `instance2.example.com`, the traffic should go to my proxy which then sees the subdomain and redirects said traffic to my instance2.

and so on...

Is this even possible? I feel so close to achieving my goal...
But since I'm really new to this whole Apache thing I need your help, since I couldn't really find anything like this scenario online. Thanks for any answers in advance!

> **Solution**

Figured it out and thought I leave my solution here if anyone has the same problem.

I added 3 new Record Sets to my hosted zone example.com, all pointing to my proxy's public address:

```
test.example.com
test2.example.com
test3.example.com
```

After that I added these lines of code to my httpd config file on my proxy server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.example.com
ProxyPass "/" "http://private IP of webserver1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://private IP of webserver1/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test2.example.com
ProxyPass "/" "http://private IP of webserver2/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://private IP of webserver2/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test3.example.com
ProxyPass "/" "http://private IP of webserver3/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://private IP of webserver3/"
</VirtualHost>
```

That's it!

Comment: just generate a virtualhost for each name and proceed with the same scheme in each.

Comment: A tip: if you have a high bandwidth website use a low end AWS Lightsail instance for your reverse proxy. Their bandwidth is much much cheaper than AWS EC2. I use Nginx for reverse proxies, it's simpler (best reason) and uses virtually no resources. I have a t2.nano running five low volume websites using Nginx, PHP, MySQL, with a CDN for caching, it rarely gets above 2% CPU.